# One-line environment variables are blank

Tags: zsh, macos

Why is my zsh doing this?

```
% MYVAR="hi" echo $MYVAR

% MYVAR="$(date)" echo $MYVAR

% export MYVAR="$(pwd)"
% echo $MYVAR
/Users/theonlygusti
```

Why are the same-line environment variables apparently not set?

Comment: For me, it works if I do `echo ${MYVAR}` instead (with {} ). I don't know how it works, though. Something to do with variable expansion I think.

Comment: Ah, I think I might have put a semicolon after "hi", which makes it work as well. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the command

```bsh
MYVAR="hi" echo $MYVAR
```

the variable `MYVAR` is set to `hi` in the environment of the `echo` command.  However, the `echo` command does not use this variable.  It is the current shell that expands the `$MYVAR` argument on the command line *before calling `echo`*.

Therefore, if the `MYVAR` variable does not exist in the shell beforehand, that command will only output a newline character.

In your last example, you set the variable in the shell before calling `echo` with the expansion of `$MYVAR` on the command line. Since the variable is set to the result of `$(pwd)` at that point (it does not need to be exported), the shell replaces `$MYVAR` with that value before calling `echo`.

The difference between

```bsh
variable=value some-command
```

and

```bsh
variable=value; some-command
```

or the equivalent

```bsh
variable=value
some-command
```

is that in the first case, the variable is set to a value in the environment of `some-command`, but not in the current shell, while in the second/third case, the variable is set in the current shell, and then `some-command` is called.  If `variable` is additionally exported, then that variable would also be available in the environment of `some-command`, would it want to use that variable.

Example:

```bsh
$ unset -v var
```

Setting a variable at the same time as calling another command sets that variable in the command's environment, but not in the local environment:

```bsh
$ var=1 sh -c 'printf "var is %s\n" "$var"'
var is 1
$ printf 'var is %s\n' "$var"
var is
```

Setting a variable in the local environment, but not exporting it sets it locally only:

```bsh
$ var=1; sh -c 'printf "var is %s\n" "$var"'
var is
$ printf 'var is %s\n' "$var"
var is 1
```

Exporting the variable makes it available in child processes:

```bsh
$ export var
$ sh -c 'printf "var is %s\n" "$var"'
var is 1
```

---

Note that

```bsh
MYVAR=$(pwd)
```

is the same as

```bsh
MYVAR=$PWD
```

Comment: I also suggest add another example using `eval`, for instance: `var=1 eval echo '$var'`, and show the difference between this and the new shell. For instance, when using `eval`, `var=1; eval echo '$var'` would still show the value of `$var`.

Comment: @aviro That would add a level of complexity that I'm not willing to commit to. Also, note that `eval` should ideally take a single-quoted string: `eval 'echo "$var"'`.  In the `bash` shell, you'll otherwise invoke the split+glob operation on the value of `$var` (test with `var='1 *   4'` in `bash`). I know this user is using `zsh`, but that may easily be missed by future readers that just read the answer.